# Droid Turbo Won't Receive Texts

Tags: sms, mms, motorola-droid, verizon

I have a Motorola Droid Turbo with Verizon as my carrier. Earlier this week (May 30th), my phone began to receive text messages intermittently. I now go hours without receiving any text messages and then all of a sudden tons of texts will come through that I had missed. Even when I receive the giant dump of texts at that time, not all of the texts will come. I've missed a bunch of texts this week that have never shown up. This is more apparent in group messages. Also, most of the time when I send a text message to someone it will tell me that it failed to send even if they actually received it.

Here are some of the things I've done to try and fix it:

- Turn my phone on and off (many times, and for long periods of times)
- Turn my WiFi on and off
- Turn my bluetooth on and off
- Backed up all of my texts on to Google Drive and then deleted them all off my phone
- Switched from using Textra to using Google Messenger
- Switched from using Google Messenger to using Verizon Messages
- Switched from using Verizon Messages to using the stock messaging app

I've read a bunch of different forums, but nothing seems to be working. I don't think it's the carrier because no one else on my plan is having problems, and I will often get a notification on my phone saying "MMS Timeout - click to retry" and then I click and it doesn't do anything.

I don't really want to reset the phone, especially since it might not fix anything. Does anyone have any other suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I went to this Verizon troubleshooting page: https://www.verizonwireless.com/support/motorola-droid-turbo-troubleshooting/#/main/device/&MOTXT1254&8617/troubleshooting_steps/17893&17885&&&&Troubleshooting&&/step/

The step that finally fixed it was sending a text to myself. I have no idea why that does anything, but it is now working fine. Hopefully it stays that way. I posted the link here in the answer so that anyone with the same problem can go there and walk through the steps.

Answer (score 1):

I switched from the android Messenger app to the Verizon Messenger app and that loaded a bunch of messages I hadn't received, and started sending to people who weren't getting my messages. so that appears to have fixed it.

Some folks on the verizon boards indicated it may be the latest android update causing the issue, and based on the fix I'm inclined to believe that.